# Autosuggest and get timezone in detail

Tags: timezone, here-api

Is there any possibility to get timezone (IANA) in place detail after confirm autosuggest place?

I have a text field with autosuggest api. After user confirms one of the results, there is second request to Here API and I need timezone name in place details.

In my first version I used this endpoints:
autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json
and for second detail request this:
geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json
with locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone and everything was OK, timezone was in response.

Now I am trying to switch to v7 of Here autosuggest API and I have a problem, I am not able to get timezone in my second (place detail) request (I am using lookup api).

And if I tried to mix versions - take place ID from first request (autosuggest api) and use it for geocode 6.2 - it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone option is not supported in Geocode and Search API V7 currently.
We will confirm that we can support the option timezone in the futuer.

For second question please see the part "Follow-up query" in documentation below.
There is lookup rest api v7.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-autosuggest-brief.html